# Redirecting users and data en a secure way

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, oauth-2.0

Users from a website (external site) needs to be redirected to my site. 
Together with the redirect, data about the user will be transferred, that should not be sent using a query-string.

However, i am in doubt how to do this in a secure way, to ensure that the redirect (and data) in fact are coming from the external partner.

---

My initial idea was to create a oauth authentication server that would return a token to the external site. The token would be returned if valid username and password are provided, and would only be valid for a set time.

Based on 
[this excellent article.](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/)

The token should then be used to transfer data from the external site to my API/MVC site. However i am stuck in how i can proceed, since i dont think a web-server can transfer a authentication token while redirecting at the same time.

How can i match a redirect and data, at the same time i make sure the external site is a trusted partner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an OAuth like approach.  Both servers have a shared secret (a GUID or something).  When rendering the form, Server A would generate a random "nonce" token.  It also gets the timestamp (for OAuth it is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970).  You string concatenate the nonce, timestamp, and shared secret and then hash them (using SHA or whatever).  This hashed value is called a signature. Then include the following as hidden input parameters:

- nonce
- timestamp
- signature

When Server B receives the response it does a few things:

- Ensure the timestamp is within X minutes of Server B's clock.
- Ensure the nonce has not been used (I'll discuss that in a second).
- Concatenate the timestamp, nonce, and Server B's copy of the shared
  secret.  Hash them using the same algorithm.
- Do a string comparison
  on the $POST['signature'] with the newly generated signature.  If
  they match then you know the request came from Server A.

Nonces are not universally unique, they are only unique for a particular time frame.  In order to track them, you must keep a dictionary in global scope.  The key is the nonce and the value is the timestamp of when it was used.  When a request comes in, lookup the nonce in the dictionary.  If the timestamp associated with it is within +/-X minutes of Server B's clock then reject the request.  If it is outside your range, or it isn't in the dictionary yet, then allow the request and add the nonce and timestamp to the dictionary.

The point is to prevent replay attacks.  A bot cannot sniff the traffic, grab the plainly visible nonce, timestamp, and signature, and sent it to Server B again with a different payload.

A note about timestamp range (X above), in OAuth it serves a single purpose: to provide a buffer between differences in server clocks.  In this regard it is usually short -- a few minutes.  In your case Server A is generating the nonce on the initial page load, so the timestamp range must include time for the user to fill out the form.  I propose that timestamps cannot be ahead of the current server time by more than a few minutes, but that they can be behind the server time by 30-60 minutes.  The downside is your nonce dictionary will have to hold the values longer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for a very good answer. :)
What if i were to add a third server, as a authentication server, could this be done using a oauth approach?

Comment: I would need more information regarding what you want to accomplish.  Would this server authenticate the user before logging into Server A?  Would it be a central server that both Server A and Server B use?